# cygpath to phpstorm.bat function fails

Tags: bash, cygwin, phpstorm

I'm using cygwin to fire up PhpStorm from the command line. Everything works but in order to do it I have to first run

```
crntproj=$(cygpath -w $PWD)
```

and then run

```
phpstorm.bat $crntproj
```

What I'd prefer is to be able to simply run `phpstorm.bat $PWD` except that doesn't work.

So I've written a bash function as follows and added to my bashrc:

```
function winpath {
path=$(cygpath -m $PWD)
echo $path
}
```

Strangely this returns what appears to be the correct folder
but when I run `phpstorm.bat winpath` PhpStorm tries to open `C:/user/project/winpath` which of course doesn't exist.

I've now tried both `-w` for windows and `-m` for mixed. That makes no difference. I also concatenated a forward slash at the end of the path to tell PhpStorm that its a folder and not a file. This also didn't fix the problem.

Can anyone explain what I'm missing?

Comment: Executing everything in the same shell with bash -c and then setting up an alias and so something like alias winpath="bash -c 'test=\"$(cygpath -w $PWD)\" && echo \"$test\"'"

Comment: Just tried this. Sadly it doesn't work. Still starts up PHP storm with the wrong path.

Comment: With the alias set, you will need to run phpstorm.bat with phpstorm.bat "$(winpath)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so put the following in `.bash_profile` and it works perfectly now

```
function winpath {
path=$(cygpath -m $PWD)
echo $path
}
```

now just run
`phpstorm.bat $(winpath)`

I've even made a couple of aliases to make it easier

```
alias pstorm='phpstorm.bat'
alias pstorm-openProj='pstorm $(winpath)'
```

So now I can just run `pstorm-openProj` in the project folder

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be solved with setting the environment variable within the ~/.bash_profile file and then restart your cygwin terminal window.

Add this line to your .bash_profile file:

`export crntproj=$(cygpath -w $PWD)`

I can't test it right now, but the goal is to set the environment variable each time you start your bash terminal.

Comment: So this put me on the right track as it seems I was using bash.bashrc not .bashrc in my profile and somehow that was causing the issue. Seems to work now. I'm not sure this is the perfect answer but it definitely pointed me towards it so thanks for that.